# PayPal Android SDK payment without PayPal account or credit card

Tags: android, paypal

Is it possible to use the Android SDK to make a payment without a PayPal account or a credit card? 
I'm searching for the feature to make an instant transfer from a bank account like a simple web-checkout. 
Currently, I can only login with an account or use a credit card.

Is the bank-account method not supported in PayPal Android SDK(1.2.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you're referring to would be ACH payments.  PayPal in general does not support this (directly).  Their version of that is logging in to a PayPal account and paying with bank funds.  They don't have any way to simply send a bank account and routing number, though, to do a direct transfer.